# Highest Possible Damage Attack in Neverwinter Nights

Tags: neverwinter-nights

Naturally, increasing [Strength](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Strength) and the weapon [Enchantment bonus](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Enhancement_bonus) will increase damage output. But, I am wondering which Level 40 Player character can achieve the highest possible damage on a single strike.

For the specifics, let's use a **+5** weapon with no other properties on an enemy with no particular [Damage Vulnerability](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Immunity), though if the answer changes with a **+10** Enchantment bonus, that might be interesting to note. And, let's only consider legal characters, meaning that you have to be able to level up from Level 1 to Level 40 via the Neverwinter Nights interface. Let's assume that items and spells provide the [full +12 Ability bonuses](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Ability_cap), but do not provide any other feats or damage-assisting spells. And let's just discuss the base game (1.69, with HotU), without any [Hakpaks](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Hak_pak).

Of course this maximal damage strike will not correspond to maximum DPS and this character might have glaring weaknesses, but this question will be much easier to answer objectively than something like "What is the best PvE character?"

Comment: Asking for "best character" would be too broad, but making too many custom restrictions are prone for [seeding](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7261/135338), not good question at all. Moreover I doubt the answer is useful to anyone else, why would someone want to have character with *"glaring weaknesses"* and only do damage into a single special monster in the game? If there would be achievement "do X damage in single hit", that may be a good question of how to achieve it and good answer.

Comment: @Sinatr: You've never played Neverwinter Nights, have you? It's an entire system, not just a single game. Module creators can create any sort of monster or weapon, so I added the "custom restrictions" just to eliminate special monsters.

Answer (score 0):

I have calculated **2230** as the maximum possible damage for a hit. But that doesn't answer the question.

I can achieve this with a [Paladin](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Paladin) 21, [Champion of Torm](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Champion_of_Torm) 14, [Weapon Master](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon_master) 5 wielding a [Scythe](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Scythe), ending with (STR/DEX/CON/INT/WIS/CHA) 14/13/8/13/14/26, having started at 14/13/8/13/12/16.

You might think like I do every time I see that Class and Ability breakdown, that certainly I could shift some of the Paladin levels to more Champion of Torm levels, but I haven't found any other build that will reach these heights.

I couldn't start with a higher Charisma score because I needed 13 in Dexterity and Intelligence for the Weapon Master prerequisite Feats and 13 in Strength for [Power Attack](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Power_attack). And the game wouldn't let me start Wisdom at any lower than 11.

And I had to save my Champion of Torm levels until the Character hit a score of 25 in Charisma, because Champion of Torm allows of the selection of [Great Smiting](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Great_smiting) as one of its bonus feats, but it only provides a bonus Feat every other level for the first ten levels.

Feats of note:

- [Great Smiting X](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Great_smiting): Add ten times Class level to any Smite hit (Requires 25 Charisma)
- [Divine Might](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_might): Add Charisma bonus to damage (Requires [Power Attack](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Power_attack))

The Damage breakdown:

- [Scythe](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Scythe): 13 (2D4, with [+5 bonus](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Enhancement_bonus))
- Strength: 12 (Strength 26, for +8 bonus, but [two-handed weapon](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Two-handed_weapon))
- [Power Attack](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Power_attack): 5 (If I have it, might as well use it)
- [Holy Avenger](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Holy_sword): 6 (1D6, from Paladin spell [Holy Sword](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Holy_sword))
- [Prayer](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Prayer): 1 (Paladin spell)
- [Divine Favor](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_favor): 5 (Paladin spell)
- [Divine Might](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_might): 14 (38 Charisma, from [Feat](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_might))
- [Divine Wrath](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_wrath): 5 (Champion of Torm [Feat](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_wrath))
- [Smite Evil](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Smite_evil): 385 ([Great Smiting X](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Great_smiting), with 35 in Paladin + Champion of Torm levels)
- Critical Hit: x5 ([Scythe](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Scythe) x4, with Weapon Master [Increased Multiplier](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Increased_multiplier) feat)

So, this can hit for 446*5 = 2230. I couldn't even fit [Extra Smiting](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Extra_smiting) and [Improved Critical (Scythe)](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Improved_critical) into this build, so if this hit misses, the character better run quickly.

One note: I suppose I could hit for slightly more on an [Undead](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Undead) enemy that doesn't have Critical Hit immunity with [Bless Weapon](https://nwn.fandom.com/wiki/Bless_weapon), but not too many Undead creatures can suffer Critical Hits.